# Openlayers - Vertex style in Control.ModifyFeature

Tags: openlayers-2

I want a custom vertex and polygon style for the Control.ModifyFeature. I want to keep the default fillColor of the polygon while editing it, not the blue. I thought this code will work but the blue is still there.

```
    var shapeStyle = {
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fillColor: colorPoly,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
    }

    var shapeStyle2 = {
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fillColor: colorPoly,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        pointRadius: 3,
    }

    var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
           "default": shapeStyle,
            "vertex": shapeStyle2
    }, {extendDefault: false});

    var newShape = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Editable",{
            styleMap: styleMap 
    });

    var edit = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(newShape,
         {
            title: "Modify Feature",
            displayClass: "olControlModifyFeature",
            styleMap: "default",
            vertexRenderIntent: "vertex"
    });
```

colorPoly is the variable containing the #color_code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModifyFeature control doesn't have styleMap property. Style of edited feature comes from "select" render intent of layer's styleMap. So you should modify "select" instead "default".

Style of selected polygon and vertices are the different things and configures separately using [vertexRenderIntent](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.vertexRenderIntent) and [virtualStyle](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.virtualStyle) properties of ModifyFeature control. For example:

```js
var vertexStyle = {
    strokeColor: "#ff0000",
    fillColor: "#ff0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 3,
    graphicName: "cross"
}

var virtual = {
    strokeColor: "#00ff00",
    fillColor: "#00ff00",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 5,
    graphicName: "triangle"
};

var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default'],
    "vertex": vertexStyle
}, {extendDefault: false});

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('features', {styleMap: styleMap});
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectors, {vertexRenderIntent: "vertex", virtualStyle: virtual}));
```